# phpmyadmin and stored procedures

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I'm not able to view subprocedures in Phpmyadmin. I have created a sub procedure via the execute query option. Is there an option to list the subprocedure and edit them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
show procedure status
```

will show you the stored procedures.

```
show create procedure MY_PROC
```

will show you the definition of a procedure. And

```
help show
```

will show you all the available options for the show command.

This will work in phpmyadmin.

Answer (score 1):

No. Although on the Phpmyadmin home page it says it supports them there is no easy way to edit them. This is a feature request on the phpmyadmin [wiki](http://wiki.phpmyadmin.net/pma/GSoC_2011_Ideas_List#Support_for_procedures) and in [sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=1353360&group_id=23067&atid=377411) but it doesn't look like anyone's implemented it.